# Grant All on All tabes in schema?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, table

I have a question about grants...

I ran the following command, assuming it would allow me to make any changes to the tables in the `public` schema:

```
grant all on all tables in schema public to User1;
```

However, when I try to add a new column I still get the error message below:

```
ERROR:  must be owner of table Tab1
```

I guess I'm just a little misinformed on the purpose of the `grant all on all` command, and how can I refine this to allow a user to add columns to a table without changing ownership?

Answer (score 0):

Right. You cannot `GRANT` the right to `ALTER` or `DROP` a table. Only the table owner or a superuser can do that.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html) describes that:

> The right to modify or destroy an object is inherent in being the object's owner, and cannot be granted or revoked in itself. (However, like all privileges, that right can be inherited by members of the owning role; see [Section 22.3.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-membership.html))

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that when you are logged in as the owner of the table. You'll be able to use DDL commands once you are logged in as the owner of the table.

Comment: This site works differently and this adds nothing new.